# How can I update data of d3 graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 graph with frequently changing datapoints that I want to show in the graph. At the moment I am redrawing the full plot every time the data object gets updated:

```
 container.remove()
 container = svg.append("g");
 drawContainer();
```

with the drawing function in drawContainer:

```
container.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(datajson)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", 3.5)
  .attr("cx", xMap)
  .attr("cy", yMap)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));})
```

I tried to simply call:

```
  container.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(newdata)
```

to add new datapoints, but this didn't make new data points visible. How can I update the plot only with the new datapoints?

Comment: here is a good read about how to create update delete points in d3 using enter exit in d3 https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something similar to calling `drawContainer();`

Instead of

```
container.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(newdata);
```

You could do:

```
var dots = container.selectAll(".dot")
   .data(newdata);
dots.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .attr("r", 3.5)
  .attr("cx", xMap)
  .attr("cy", yMap)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));});
dots.exit().remove();
```

For a complete example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218